# Script for capitalizing first letter of words in filename

Tags: linux, file, capitalize

'm trying to rename the tables of mysql databases to have capital first letters in each word so for example a table called "renametable" would become "RenameTable". I had a couple of scripts from a colleague that managed to do that by getting table names from a correct database but it doesn't work anymore as we've changed our servers. I'm not sure what changed so I'll post the scripts here in case you can help me.

First thing was to place the 2 scripts in /root folder, 
then navigate to mysql database folder where the data is and run:

```
ls -1 | xargs -i /root/rename2.sh {}
```

**rename2.sh:**

```
force=`echo $1 | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
if [ -f $1 ];then
 mv $1 $force
fi
```

After that I had to run another command:

```
ls -1 ../<gooddb> | xargs -i /root/rename.sh {}
```

where gooddb is a database with the correct table naming structure

**rename.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

lower=`echo $1 | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`

if [ -f $lower ];then
 mv $lower $1
fi
```

Now when I run first command I get the error:

```
: not founde2.sh: 2: /root/rename2.sh:
/root/rename2.sh: 7: /root/rename2.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
```

And the error for the second command afterwards:

```
xargs: /root/rename.sh: No such file or directory file
```

even though I've allowed full control over those 2 files.

Comment: How would you parse "seedoneat"? Is that "SeeDonEat" or "SeedOneAt"? Regardless, this: `];then` is gonna be a problem - fix it to say `] ; then`...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an overwritten line:

```
: not founde2.sh: 2: /root/rename2.sh:
```

Windows line ends (`$'\r'`) involved, maybe?